# UPDATE SQL TABLE subtract new value to stored value with bind variables or bind parameters

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am having difficulties to properly **UPDATE** this information in MySQL database, I am trying to subtract -5 out of the current value of my stock_quantity. I added a couple of tries but none of them work.

Any ideas?

Table name: products

```
 item_id  product_name  department_name  price   stock_quantity
 -------  ------------  ---------------  ------  --------------

   1        Samsung S9                     899     59
   2        Samsung S8                     519.98  49
   3        Samsung S7                     297.89  27
   4        iPhone X                       1299    50    
   5        iPhone 8+                      699.99  10
   6        iPhone 8                       639.95  8
   7        iPhone 7+                      579.99  11
   8        iPhone 7                       399     6






 function updateProduct() {
   console.log( "Updating stock...\n");
       var query = connection.query(
       "UPDATE products SET ? WHERE ?",
     [
        {
          //all these alternatives seem not to work
            stock_quantity:  "'stock_quantity' -5"
          // alternatives 2
            stock_quantity:  "stock_quantity" -5
          // alternatives 3
            stock_quantity:  "stock_quantity"+" -5"
          // alternatives 4
            stock_quantity:  stock_quantity +" -5"
        },
        {
            item_id : 4
        },
    ],
    function (err, res) {
        console.log(res.affectedRows + " products updated!\n");
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**

What you've attempted is binding the value `'stock_quantity' -5` to your stock_quantity field.

As you are working with binded parameters, you will need before your `UPDATE` statement to get the `'stock_quantity'` value (example: in oldValue var).

Once you've got that value, you will be able to update the `'stock_quantity'` by doing `stock_quantity:  oldValue - 5`

**Old :**

You should write something like

```
UPDATE ... SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity - 5 WHERE ...
```

Which gives..

```
stock_quantity:  "'stock_quantity' = 'stock_quantity' - 5"
```

This will make your request looks like :

```
UPDATE products SET 'stock_quantity' = 'stock_quantity' - 5 WHERE 'item_id' = 4
```

Comment: I did try your input and had no success, I am using something call Bind parameters—also called dynamic parameters or bind variables. I read a brief explanation here:

Comment: Oh, I see.. It will not work as the value `'stock_quantity' = 'stock_quantity' - 5` is binded to the stock_quantity field..

Comment: You should get the stock_quantity for the actual item_id, and sending that quantity -5

Answer (score 0):

The query you are looking for is something like this, here we are subtracting five from the current `stock_quantity` for the item with the id '4':

`UPDATE products SET stock_quantity=stock_quantity - 5 WHERE item_id=4`

So your code would look like:

```
function updateProduct() {
   console.log( "Updating stock...\n");
   var query = connection.query(
     "UPDATE products SET stock_quantity=stock_quantity - 5 WHERE item_id=4", function(err, res) {
       console.log(res.affectedRows + " products updated!\n");
   });
}
```

Comment: I am using Bind parameters—also called dynamic parameters or bind variables.
Don't know if it is allowed but I've added a link to a site that explains the used of bind parameters quite nicely.

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters